# Implicit parameter and function

Tags: haskell, parameters, ghc, implicit, wordnet

I have a problem considering implicit parameters in Haskell (GHC). I have a function *f*, that assumes the implicit parameter *x*, and would like to encapsulate it in a context by applying *f* to *g*

```
f :: (?x :: Int) => Int -> Int
f n = n + ?x

g :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
g t = let ?x = 5 in t
```

But when i try to evaluate

```
g f 10
```

I get an error that *x* is not bound, e.g.:

```
Unbound implicit parameter (?x::Int)
  arising from a use of `f'
In the first argument of `g', namely `f'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `g f 10'
```

Can anybody tell me, what I am doing wrong?

(I am trying to get the WordNet Interface for Haskell to work - http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/HWordNet/ - and it uses on implicit parameters in the above manner, and I keep getting errors as the one above when I try to compile it)

Answer (score 8):

The first parameter of `g` must be of type `((?x::Int) => Int -> Int)` to clarify that ?x should be passed to `f`. This can be dony be enabling Rank2Types (or RankNTypes). Unfortunately, GHC cannot infer this type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

f :: (?x::Int) => Int -> Int
f n = n + ?x

g :: ((?x::Int) => Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
g f = let ?x = 5 in f`
```

Now `g f 10` works.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that `?x` isn't bound at the point it's referenced. You and I can see that `?x` will be bound within `g`, but the compiler can't. One (confusing) solution is to change

```
g f 10
```

to

```
g (let ?x = 5 in f) 10
```