# Implicitly call function

Tags: haskell, implicit

I need to find a way to implicitly call a function in Haskell in a similar way that you can do using `implicit` functions in Scala.

I've looked into using `{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}` like shown in [Implicit parameter and function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141600/implicit-parameter-and-function) but I can't figure out how to achieve something similar without explicitly defining it.

This is a very reduced version of my code

```
a :: Int -> Int
a n = n + 1

b :: [Char] -> Int
b cs = length cs
```

I want to be able to run

```
Test> a "how long" -- outputs 8, as it implicitly calls a (b "how long")
```

as well as

```
Test> a 5 -- outputs 6
```

Comment: I'm not a haskeller but it seems that you're looking for single dispatching, dispatching based on argument type? You can create an instance of a for strings

Comment: You can do that by defining a typeclass, and then create instances for `String` and `Int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you here describe is [*ad hoc polymorphism* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism). In Haskell that is achieved through [*type classes* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class).

We can for example define a class:

```
class Foo c where
    a :: c -> Int
```

Now we can define two instances of `Foo`: an instance for `Int`, and an instance for `String`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Foo [Char] where
    a = length

instance Foo Int where
    a = (+) 1
```

Next we thus can call `a` with:

```
Prelude> a "how long"
8
Prelude> a (5 :: Int)
6
```

Comment: Is there any way of extending this so you can ignore the functions and convert automatically, such as `value :: Int \n value = "how long"` and it will call length without explicitly writing it?

Comment: @w1220 No, not generally. There is something for `String`, specifically (the `OverloadedStrings` extension), but I strongly recommend that you do not use it for this. Learn to write Haskell, not Scala, in your Haskell code.